# How to display preview picture for private dailymotion video?

Tags: video, preview, dailymotion-api

I have private video on dailymotion. I need to display their preview pictures on my websites.

I cannot use the embed API because it doesn't work with private videos.

Has anyone found a way to achieve this ?

Regars,
Mac.

Answer (score 0):

You sure can use the data API to get all info you need on your private video, but you need to authenticate.

If you want to play the video using dailymotion player, you should request its [`private_id`](https://developer.dailymotion.com/api#video-private_id-field). You can play your video using this id, but beware that once you disclose this private id, your video can no longer be considered as private!